# Vuex - Modify state objects only on getters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-cli-3

I have a lot of state modules with relations, here are two of my main states:

channels.js

```
const state = {
    channels: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'E-mail'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'SMS'
        }
    ]
}

const getters = {
    channel(state) {
        return (id) => {
            return _.find(state.channels, (channel) => {
                return channel.id == id
            })
        }
    },
    channels(state) {
        return state.channels
    }
}
```

wallets.js

```
const state = {
    wallets: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Wallet A",
            channel_id: 1
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Wallet B",
            channel_id: 2
        }
    ]
}

const getters = {
    wallet(state) {
        return (id) => {
            return _.find(state.wallets, (wallet) => {
                return wallet.id == id
            })
        }
    },
    wallets(state) {
        return state.wallets
    }
}
```

When I call the getter `wallets/wallets`, instead of return:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Wallet A",
        channel_id: 1
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Wallet B",
        channel_id: 2
    }
]
```

Is there any way to return like this?

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Wallet A",
        channel: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'E-mail'
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Wallet B",
        channel: {
            id: 2,
            name: 'SMS'
        }
    }
]
```

### Edit

---

Based on 8bit answer, I tried the following code, but no success:

```
import {http} from "../../support/http";
import axios from "axios";

const state = {
    actions: [],
    bots: [],
    conditions: []
}

const getters = {
    action(state) {
        return (id) => {
            return _.find(state.actions, (action) => {
                return action.id == id
            })
        }
    },
    actions(state) {
        return state.actions
    },
    bot(state) {
        return (id) => {
            return _.find(state.bots, (bot) => {
                return bot.id == id
            })
        }
    },
    bots(state, getters, rootState, rootGetters) {
        return state.bots.map((bot) => {
            let channels = bot.channels.map((item) => {
                let channel = rootGetters["channels/channel"](item.channel_id)
                let wallet = rootGetters["wallets/wallet"](item.wallet_id)

                return {
                    ...item,
                    channel,
                    wallet
                }
            })

            return {
                ...bot,
                channels: channels
            }
        })
    },
    condition(state) {
        return (id) => {
            return _.find(state.conditions, (condition) => {
                return condition.id == id
            })
        }
    },
    conditions(state) {
        return state.conditions
    },
    primaryConditions(state) {
        return _.filter(state.conditions, (condition) => {
            return condition.primary == true
        })
    },
    secondaryConditions(state) {
        return _.filter(state.conditions, (condition) => {
            return condition.primary == false
        })
    }
}

const actions = {
    fetchData({dispatch}) {
        function getActions() {
            return http.get('idr/actions')
        }

        function getBots() {
            return http.get('idr/bots')
        }

        function getConditions() {
            return http.get('idr/conditions')
        }

        return axios.all([
            getActions(),
            getBots(),
            getConditions()
        ]).then(axios.spread(function (actions, bots, conditions) {
            dispatch('setActions', actions.data.data)
            dispatch('setBots', bots.data.data)
            dispatch('setConditions', conditions.data.data)
        })).catch(error => console.error(error))
    },
    insertChannel({commit}, channel) {
        commit('INSERT_CHANNEL', channel)
    },
    setActions({commit}, actions) {
        commit('SET_ACTIONS', actions)
    },
    setBot({commit}, bot) {
        commit('SET_BOT', bot)
    },
    setBots({dispatch}, bots) {
        _.each(bots, (bot) => {
            dispatch('setBot', bot)
        })
    },
    updateBot({commit}, data) {
        commit('UPDATE_BOT', data)
    },
    deleteBot({commit}, bot) {
        commit('DELETE_BOT', bot)
    },
    setConditions({commit}, conditions) {
        commit('SET_CONDITIONS', conditions)
    }
}

const mutations = {
    INSERT_CHANNEL(state, data) {
        let index = _.findIndex(state.bots, {id: data.bot_id});

        state.bots[index].channels.push(data.channel)
    },
    SET_ACTIONS(state, actions) {
        state.actions = actions
    },
    SET_BOT(state, data) {
        let index = _.findIndex(state.bots, {'id': data.id})

        index > -1 ? state.bots[index] = data : state.bots.push(data)
    },
    UPDATE_BOT(state, data) {
        let index = _.findIndex(state.bots, {id: data.bot_id});

        state.bots[index].channels = data.channels
    },
    DELETE_BOT(state, bot) {
        let bot_index = _.findIndex(state.bots, {id: bot.id});

        state.bots.splice(bot_index, 1)
    },
    SET_CONDITIONS(state, conditions) {
        state.conditions = conditions
    }
}

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

The getter is returning the data correctly, but when I add an specific bot to a data property the new properties go away...

[image]

Bot is added to data this way:

```
<list-item v-for="bot in botsGetter" :key="bot.id" class="white-hover">
    <dropdown class="align-center">
            <template slot="menu">
                <li><a href="#" title="" @click.prevent="editBot(bot)">Editar</a></li>
            </template>
        </dropdown>
</list-item>

editBot(bot) {
    this.$bus.$emit('hide.dropdown')

    this.editBotModal = bot
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have access to rootGetters from any getter in any module, check the Vuex API [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#getters).

So you could write your `wallets` getter like this:

```
wallets(state, getters, rootState, rootGetters) {
  return state.wallets.map((wallet) => {
    const channel = rootGetters["channel/channel"](wallet.channel_id);

    return {
      ...wallet,
      channel
    }
  }
}
```

Or alternatively, if you keep your state normalized (which it seems you do), then you can use [denormalize](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/master/docs/api.md#denormalizeinput-schema-entities), but you might have to actually originally normalize the store using the same library too, and keep a set of schemas.

Comment: One of my state modules, in each part of the application can load one or more modules, for example: in some moment it may need one of the following modules: `stateB_id, stateC_id or stateD_id`. How can I make this dynamic? One hour I might want to call only `stateB_id and stateC_id`, another only `stateD_id`. Can you think of something?

Comment: @CaioKawasaki Please show the code how you add a "bot" to the data object, also I don't understand you first comment if you can clarify please or represent in pseudo code.

Comment: Hm adding a "bot" to a data property causes it to lose data in it's channel array, makes no sense. Let's first fix your mutations maybe that's the problem. You can't update arrays like you do in your mutations. You need to return a fresh new array for almost every case. You can't mutate the array already existing in your state because Vue won't pick it up and make it reactive (or will ignore the new/changed property) - and this can make for weird issues. Check out [this](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) from the docs.

Comment: Or even better [this](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/03/05/vue-js-reactivity/). For instance in your `SET_BOT` mutation you can't just `state.bots.push(data)`. You need to make a new array and add that item, so `[...state.bots, data]`.

Comment: I may discovered the issue... I'm passing the data as props, and its not reactive...